# how to get post data

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

my code is below in javascript but response is null.

```
var query = FB.Data.query("SELECT link_id, owner, owner_comment, created_time, title, summary, url, image_urls FROM link WHERE owner="+response.id+"url = 'http://xys.com/xyz'");
                 query.wait(function(rows) {alert(rows);return false;
   if(!rows[0]){
   alert('You have not Liked the Page.');
   }else{
   alert('Congratulations!!!');
   //document.promocode.submit();
   }
                 });
```

Comment: `FB.Data.query` is an outdated method – use `FB.api` instead, and react to the result within the callback function.